# FLoating Horizontal Scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, scrollbar

I'm using this JQuery Plugin that allows for the horizontal scroll bar to float when the data is long, but I can't get it to work. Been trying for ages. The plugin can be found [Here](https://github.com/Amphiluke/floating-scroll).

In the docs, all it says to do is attach it to a static container, which I did. Any body else having this problem/Know the solution?

Here is what I tried so far. (I've been usnig the window snapped to the side, maybe thats the problem.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="floating-scroll-master/src/jquery.floatingscroll.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".child").floatingScroll();
    });        
</script>
<style>
.parent {
    background-color: grey;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.child {
    max-height: 1500px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='parent'>
<pre class='child'>            <p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.H    ello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hel    lo.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.    </p><p>Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.H    ello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hel    lo.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.</p>
</pre>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

SO is messing up the editing for the `<p>`'s, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the plugin to the div, and set fixed value for the width and height of div.